# Convertir posiciones de una cadena a fecha en java

Tags: java, string, date

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que involucra la manipulación de una cadena con un formato CURP. Aunque todo el programa ya funciona, no logro validar las fechas ya que hago lo siguiente:

```
     inicialAPaterno=curp.charAt(0);
     inicialApaterno1=curp.charAt(1);
     inicialAMaterno=curp.charAt(2);
     inicialNombre=curp.charAt(3);
     ano=curp.charAt(4);
     ano1=curp.charAt(5);
     mes=curp.charAt(6);
     mes1=curp.charAt(7);
     dia=curp.charAt(8);
     dia1=curp.charAt(9);
     sexo=curp.charAt(10);
     entidad=curp.charAt(11);
     entidad1=curp.charAt(12);
```

Y eso lo hago para separar caracteres de la cadena y aunque mi programa ya hace lo que debería, me gustaría convertir a fecha las posiciones `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` y `9`. Eso para validar y poder mostrar en una caja de texto los resultados correctos.

Comment: De qué tipo están declarados annio, annio1 y los demás valores que compondrían la fecha `String`o `Integer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una cadena tomando los 6 valores y convertirla a fecha en formato `ddMMyy`. También, viendo que haces 6 llamadas a `charAt`:

```
 ano=curp.charAt(4);
 ano1=curp.charAt(5);
 mes=curp.charAt(6);
 mes1=curp.charAt(7);
 dia=curp.charAt(8);
 dia1=curp.charAt(9);
```

Se podría optimizar un poco, obteniendo mediante **[`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))** el rango de valores que contiene lo que sería la fecha con algo como:

```
String mDate=curp.substring(4, 10);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/P5LDNt)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class ConvertirFecha
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        /*
         * Simularemos algunos valores de curp
         * apiicando a cada uno substring
         */

        String curp="ABCD100801MYZ";
        String curpDate=curp.substring(4,10);
        Date mDate=parseDate(curpDate);
        System.out.println(mDate);

        System.out.println("Otras pruebas");
        curp="HIJK091122FAB";
        curpDate=curp.substring(4,10);
        System.out.println(parseDate(curpDate));

        curp="PQRS220874FL;";
        curpDate=curp.substring(4,10);
        System.out.println(parseDate(curpDate));

    }

    public static Date parseDate(String dateStr) {
        final SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
        try {
            return date_format.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Fri Aug 10 00:00:00 GMT 2001

Otras pruebas
Wed Nov 09 00:00:00 GMT 2022
Thu Aug 22 00:00:00 GMT 1974
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente tomar el `substring` con tu dato y convertirlo con un `SimpleDateFormatter`:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    Date d = sdf.parse(curp.substring(4, 10));
```

en el caso que no se puede construir un `Date` de los caracteres, se tira una `ParseException`.

**¡Ojo!** el parser es bien flexible en su trabajo, por ejemplo va convertir una "fecha" como "170336" (36. de mar 2017) en el 5. de abríl 2017, que es calendariamente correcto, pero probablemente no suficiente para una validación.

La manera más fácil de incluir una validación sería:

```
public boolean validar(String fecha){
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
        Date d = sdf.parse(fecha);
        return fecha.equals(sdf.format(d));
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Luego se puede validar la fecha con:

```
boolean valido = validar(curp.substring(4,10));
```

Answer (score -1):

puedes usar una expresion  regular para verificar que este correcta.

```
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    private boolean validarCURP(String curp)
      { 
         String regex ="[A-Z]{1}[AEIOU]{1}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}" +
        "(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])" +"[HM]{1}"+"(AS|BC|BS|CC|CS|CH|CL|CM|DF|DG|GT|GR|HG|JC|MC|MN|MS|NT|NL|OC|PL|QT|QR|SP|SL|SR|TC|TS|TL|VZ|YN|ZS|NE)" + [B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{3}" +"[0-9A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$";
          Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(regex);
          if(!patron.matcher(curp).matches())
           { return false;
           }else
           { return true;
           }
       }
```

Esta funcion recibe como parametro un string que es el curp y te devuelve true o false dependiendo de si esta correcto o no el curp.